# Redux-form: How can I get the value of a name property passed into a Field via FieldArray?

Tags: redux, redux-form

Using `FieldArray` with `redux-form`, the name gets passed to the `Field` like this:

```
<Field 
    name={`${obj}.description`}
    component={TextField}
    hintText={`${obj}.description`}
/>
```

The `name` is a `string` with value `"myArray[0].description"`.

Obviously, redux-form performs a lookup of this property, in the array element for display in the `Field`. How can I do the same? I want to display the **value** of the myArray[0].description property (not inside a `Field`). All the stateless component has, however, is the `fields` object which contains the number of elements but is not itself an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be nested `Fields`:

`` <Field 
    name={`${obj}.description`}
    component={TextField}
    hintText={
        <Field name={`${obj}.description`} component={(props) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <span>{props.input.value}</span>
                </div>
            )
        }}/>
    }
/> ``